# Whats the best way to transport a file to a different server?

Tags: php, scaling

Im running a file host thats grown beyond the capacity of a single server, and I need to implement multiple server storage of files. I'd like to do this as cheap as possible, so those fancy mass storage methods are out of the question. I simply want to move a file thats uploaded by the user to the "gateway" server, which hosts all the http and mysql, to one of the media servers. It can either be done at the end of the user's request, or via cron every couple of minutes.

At this point the only method Im truly familiar with, is using ftp_put php function, and simply ftping the file to a different server, but I've had problems with this method in the past, especially for larger files, and a lot of the files that will be getting transferred will be over 100mb.

Can anyone suggest a good solution for this? Preferably Im looking for a purely software solution... hopefully nothing more than a php/bash script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method that requires no programmatic setup, and is quite secure is to mount a folder from the other server, and use php to save to that directory like you would normally.

You don't have to use sshfs, there are a bunch of other ways to provide the same solution. I would use sshfs for this situation as it works across ssh, and therefore is secure and relatively easy to setup.

To achieve this (using sshfs):

1. Install [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html)
2. Mount a ssfs file to a folder accessable to php
3. Use a php script to store the files within the sshfs mount, and therefore on the other server.

Another method is to setup an [rsync](http://www.samba.org/rsync/) command between the two using crontab.

Comment: Does it get sent over to the other server as soon as a file is saved into the mounted directory? What about performance wise, if there are several files being "synced" at the same time?

Comment: I've used this method to mount a file system from a remote server (through a tunnelled internet connecton) and only experienced slight delays.  I use this method to access and manipulate large volumes of files on a local development server, and have not experienced much noticable latency.

With sshfs, the files are synced near-instantly so it feels like a local filesystem, performance should be fairly good but if you have a large server you may need to investicate a SAN.

Answer (score 1):

you can write a bash script that run in cron

and use command line like scp or sftp or rsync

example :

```
[bash]# scp filename alice@galaxy.example.com:/home/alice
```

Copy "filename" into alice's home directory on the remote galaxy.example.com server

Answer (score 0):

Use cron, a bash script, and rsync.

**cron:** "Cron is a time-based job scheduler in Unix-like computer operating systems. 'cron' is short for 'chronograph'."

**bash:** "Bash is a free software Unix shell written for the GNU Project."

**rsync:** "rsync is a software application for Unix systems which synchronizes files and directories from one location to another while minimizing data transfer using delta encoding when appropriate."

In summary, *place the rsync command in a bash script and get cron to run it at regular intervals.*

See [here](http://www.samba.org/rsync/examples.html) for some examples: